# Probabilistic meaning of rectangular area

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $\xi$ be a random variable with $p(x)$ density function, which is like a normal distribution (i.e. $p(x)$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$). Denote by $s$ the maximum area of rectangle inside $p(x)$ and real line:
$$
s = \max\left\{a\cdot|I| \colon a\cdot\chi_I(x)\le p(x)\right\}
$$
where $\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of $I\subset\mathbb{R}$, $|I|$ is the length of interval $I$ and the maximum is taken over all possible combination of $a\in\mathbb{R},\,I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.
It can be shown that $s$ can be anything from $(0,1]$.

Is there any reference to paper/book/... about this maximal rectangular area ?

Does $s$ represent a probability of some event related to $\xi$ ?

Comment: It is probably obvious but what is $\chi_I(x)$? The length of the interval $I$? What is $a$?

Comment: @MaxFt I hope I made it clear the notations.

Answer (score 0):

The value $s$ does not represent a probability of any event for $\xi$, but it does represent a *lower bound* of the probability over the same interval on which the rectangle in question was constructed.  To see this, we let $\mathscr{S}$ be the set of all closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, so that your maximised area is:

$$s \equiv \max_{\mathcal{S} \in \mathscr{S}} A(\mathcal{S}) \quad \quad \quad A(\mathcal{S}) \equiv | \mathcal{S} | \inf_{x \in \mathcal{S}} p(x).$$

Now, defining the set $\mathcal{E} \equiv \operatorname{argmax}_{\mathcal{S} \in \mathscr{S}}  A(\mathcal{S}) $ we can observe that:

$$\mathbb{P} ( \xi \in \mathcal{E} ) = \int \limits_{\mathcal{E}} p(x) dx \geqslant \inf_{x \in \mathcal{E}} p(x) \int \limits_{\mathcal{E}} dx = | \mathcal{E} | \inf_{x \in \mathcal{E}} p(x) = A( \mathcal{E} ).$$